# Error shows 'cannot find module firebase-functions' when deploying a firebase project

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

When I am trying to deploy a firebase project it shows an error message 'cannot find module firebase-functions' in npm console.The steps(node commands) I have done are:

1. npm install -g firebase-tools
2. firebase login
3. firebase init

and finally where I stucked is
4. firebase deploy

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure you've installed node modules *in your functions directory*: `cd functions && npm install`

Comment: Thanks ."cd functions" So is it necessary that there will be folder named functions?

Comment: Okey thanks. It worked.I could successfully deploy my project.But now when I enter the project url ,which is get from the hosting tab in firebase console, in browser it shows  "Site not found" message.What else I should be done?Please reply.

Comment: I am having issues as well. Please see the following error: `Invalid name: "@types/jsonwebtoken"`
Any clue?

Answer (score 13):

It's simple! If it says can't find module firebase-functions then install them.

```
npm install firebase-functions
```

Comment: This is not a very good answer, especially considering that he is most likely in the wrong folder.

Comment: He never said he was in a wrong folder. He was just not aware of the commands @Pieter

Comment: If he knew then he woulnd't have the problem.  It can be derived that he was in the wrong folder based on the steps he posted.
Please note that my comment wasn't an insult to you but rather to serve as a warning to future readers to confirm the folder.

Comment: sure @Pieter i m not taking it in a bad way :) Its nice that you shared yours opinion :)

Answer (score 10):

you should install node_modules in the functions directory in your project

```
cd functions
npm install
```

then run firebase deploy

Comment: I had just pulled a request from a security bot on GitHub and hadn't updated my functions, so this worked for me when I tried `firebase deploy` in the correct folder with no luck before trying this. The above command `npm install firebase-functions` didn't work, but changing directories did work.

Answer (score 6):

Could be that you didn't follow the instructions provided when running "firebase init". You should press space and then enter in order to select the option you want - possibly that's why there was no functions folder.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you have requires with wrong cases!

The firebase function file system seems to be case sensitive.

So if you do

```
const { myStuff } = require('./mystuff');
```

but the file is actually named `myStuff.js`, it may very well work locally, but fails on build

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using @nrwl/nx monorepo and moved /functions to /apps and all my node pages are in the root project folder.
What worked for me is to replace the double quotes with single quotes

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
```

to

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue scratching my head since I could clearly see `firebase-functions` in my package.json and it was definitely installed.

Then I remembered that I'm deploying (inherently production), and `firebase-functions` was in my **devDependencies** section of package.json instead of **dependencies**.

In case someone runs into this same issue, double check that `firebase-functions` is in **dependencies** as it won't be included in the resulting bundle or deployment otherwise. In my case, I needed to explicitly add it to my functions/package.json.

E.g. -> [Move a module from devDependencies to dependencies in npm package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903002/move-a-module-from-devdependencies-to-dependencies-in-npm-package-json)