# Move a module from devDependencies to dependencies in npm package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

Is there any short command to move a module from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in package.json?

I find myself always doing this:

```
npm uninstall <module_name> --save-dev 
npm install <module_name> --save
```

Is there a shorter approach to this?

Comment: If you care about maintaining the same versions in your `package-lock.json`, and merely marking the dependency as a dev dependency, then the approach mentioned in this answer should be the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57032462/3575560

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Yes! to move a module from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`:

`npm install <module_name> --save-prod`

Answer (score 449):

Shorthand to move from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` (prod):

```
npm i <module_name> -P
```

If you want to do the opposite (i.e. move a module from `dependencies` to `devDependencies`) just do:

```
npm install <module_name> --save-dev
```

or shorthand:

```
npm i <module_name> -D
```

Comment: shorthand `npm i module-example -D` will also work to move from prod to dev, as well as `npm i module-example -P` to move from dev to prod dependencies

Comment: @Andriy thanks, didn't thought about it. Will update the answer!

Comment: If you're using yarn instead, you need to remove it first from dependencies with `yarn remove <module_name>` and then re-adding it into devDependencies with `yarn add <module_name> --dev`

Comment: What If I just move the dependency from `dependencies` to `devDependencies` in `package.json`? The lock file doesn't seem to store any information regarding dev or production

Comment: better to include the version with @ to be sure it will be the same version

Comment: @Eugenio What you are saying is removing & reinstalling it. Is there any way to move dependency from dev to prod in `yarn`?

Comment: This command will not simply "move" package, but rather install package in the desired place (either dependencies or devDependencies). Don't forget to check the version after install - it could be different.

Answer (score 62):

**In yarn:**

Move a module from `devDependencies` to `dependencies`:

```
yarn remove <module_name> --dev && yarn add <module_name>
```

Move a module from `dependencies` to `devDependencies` :

```
yarn remove <module_name> && yarn add <module_name> --dev
```

As said in the comments, the command actually deletes the module and reinstall it in the new place.

Comment: Is this really right? Is there no way in yarn to move things from `dependencies` to `devDependencies` without removing and re-adding?

Comment: @LondonRob that's the only way i've found

Comment: This is not moving, This is simply deleting the package and installing it again

Comment: @seeker_of_bacon Nothing is running in the background here. You might be confusing `&&` with `&`.

Comment: Note, this might change the version of the package!

Comment: As @CagriUysal pointed out, this will update the package version, which actually caused a lot of issues in my case.

Comment: this should have more downvotes than upvotes for the reasons above ..

Answer (score 25):

The problem with using `npm` or `yarn` commands is that there is a chance that **the version that is re-added is a different version than the one that is currently used.** If this is what you want - **both** a move and an upgrade - then go ahead and use the accepted answer.

If not, simply **manually edit your `package.json`** to move the line from the `devDependencies` object to the `dependencies` object (creating it if necessary). You can go the other direction too.

<strike>The lock file doesn't hold any information about if things are prod or dev dependencies, so that doesn't need to be updated.</strike> You can do a `npm`/`yarn install` afterwards to fix up any flags in the lock files.

Comment: While there is only a single `dependencies` top-level section in `package-lock.json`, each entry potentially has a `dev` flag to indicate whether it is a dev dependency or a transitive dependency of one. See https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json#dev "If [dev is] true then this dependency is either a development dependency ONLY of the top level module or a transitive dependency of one. This is false for dependencies that are both a development dependency of the top level and a transitive dependency of a non-development dependency of the top level."

Comment: I wish I saw this answer first. Don't forget that updating to a new version potentially introduces breaking changes - as I forgot myself.

Answer (score 6):

The issue of using npm install is that you end up with updated versions. What worked for me is:

1. Moving them to the intended part (dev, or prod)
2. Removing them from **node_modules** folder
3. Execute `npm install`

That kept all versions intact.

Answer (score 3):

If your project doesn't have a lockfile or a shrinkwrap file yet, you can simply move the corresponding line in your `package.json`.

(I'm not recommending not using lockfiles)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find an answer for this question for people that uses Yarn, but it hasn't a command for this matter yet.
Although, I believe it is not essential anyway. 
Physically (in the Node modules folder) there are no difference between a dependency listed for production and the ones listed for development in your package.json, they'll go to the same place (node_modules). 
So, if you need to switch a dependency from ***devDependencies*** to ***dependecies*** you can go to your package.json and move manually with no need to run a new install or remove the dependency and then install it again with the ***dev*** flag.
For me, it's not so great at all to manage the package.json manually, but Yarn is not as advanced as NPM in all functionalities, thus that's a thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

For Yarn, I moved them manually inside `package.json` and then ran `yarn install`. Yarn lock file does not get updated, so I think this is fine.